# Load a visualforce page within another visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a visualforce page which shows engagement metrics on the contact record using the contract id and contact email.

I'm trying to find a way to show an overview from the account record for each contact so however many contacts there are on an account, that's how many engagement metrics would appear on this page.

I've got a page which displays all the related contact Ids and Emails, and I can force a single contact to load the page with the engagement metrics via a command button (though it does open in a new window instead of section with the button), but I'm unsure of how to to make them all load automatically in the section instead, and was wondering if it's even possible.

Below is the image with the data I can load which would need to be passed through to contact metric visualforce page for each list in the table.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to convert the content of your page to a component, and then you can call it from different areas.

To convert your page to a component, first create a new component, such as `contactEngagement`. Your content should look something like this:

```
<apex:component controller="ContactEngagementController">
  <apex:attribute name="contactId" type="Id" description="The Contact Id to use" />
  <!-- the rest of your code here -->
</apex:component>
```

Now, in your contact page that you currently have, you'd replace the content with:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
  <c:contactEngagement contactId="{!Contact.Id}" />
</apex:page>
```

And for your new account version:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="theContact">
    <c:contactEngagement contactId="{!theContact.Id}" />
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Note that this is just an example concept. You may want to use an extension Apex class in order to optimize the number of database calls you need, or to control the order of the contacts, etc.

Comment: That's what I was missing. I've converted the the visualforce page into a component and now I'm able to load it in the visualforce pages. Thank you.